# Multiply rows with other rows and return total value

Tags: excel, formula

I am working on a crypto tracking sheet.

I have a datatable with a column referencing values from another sheet's datatable with a INDEX formula.

I need each column's rows multiplied by the USD Price column and then return the total value at the bottom of each column.

I tried with another INDEX formula but it is giving me an error. Is it because I am trying to INDEX a cell which contains a INDEX formula?

Here's a link to my Excel sheet with the formulas, you will find my attempt at the bottom of the sheet. It returns #VALUE! error.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AocHOUIO1meDklmoEZkC53Zg6Z3S

Here is a screenshot if you prefer not to click on my OneDrive link.
[image: Excel Screenshot]

Comment: Not many of us are going to click your random like to an Excel file due to security concerns. I suggest screenshot your data (or a small sample) and your formulas.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks for that. I simply linked my Excel because I saw in another thread that it was easier when the file was linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the formula you are trying to use, the foremost being that even when working correctly, it will not give you the results you are looking for. If you change your formula from

```
=SUM([Yobit]*INDEX(CMC_Prices[Coin.price_usd],MATCH([Coin Symbol],CMC_Prices[Coin.symbol],0)))
```

to

```
=SUM([Yobit])*INDEX(CMC_Prices[Coin.price_usd],MATCH([Coin Symbol],CMC_Prices[Coin.symbol],0))
```

then hold CTRL+SHIFT and press ENTER, you will get a result, but it isn't the correct result for what you're trying to accomplish, as it will SUM the Yobit column, and multiply it by the first value returned by the INDEX/MATCH, which is the value for the ABY Coin only.

Here is what I ended up doing to get the correct result:

First of all, your USD Price column is already pulling the values you're trying to INDEX/MATCH with that formula, so you don't need it in the formula, as it won't actually INDEX/MATCH each row as you want it to.

Secondly, it isn't formatted as a number, and changing the format doesn't seem to help at all (to see this, try testing the formula =M2+M3 against the formula =SUM(M2:M3) to see what I mean). You can fix this by simply adding *1 to the end of the formulas in column M, or typing a 1 into a cell, and pasting special using the "Multiply" operation into the M column.

Once that is done, you can achieve what you want with an array formula (which is simply a formula that applies to all cells in a range). In your "Totals" row, type this formula:

```
=SUM(IF(CoinsAssets[Yobit]="", 0, CoinsAssets[Yobit]*CoinsAssets[USD Price]))
```

Then hold CTRL+SHIFT and press ENTER. You should see this in the formula bar now:

```
{=SUM(IF(CoinsAssets[Yobit]="", 0, CoinsAssets[Yobit]*CoinsAssets[USD Price]))}
```

This will give you the correct calculation for each of these you are wanting.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Hello Night1505,

THANK YOU!!! It worked perfectly! :) And your way of explaining it makes it a lot clearer to me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)